# Accessing Postgresql via deadpool_postgres, tokio_postgres and rustls

Tags: postgresql, rust, rust-tokio, rust-axum, tokio-postgres

I try to use [deadpool_postgres](https://docs.rs/deadpool-postgres/latest/deadpool_postgres/) to access a Postgres database from my [Axum](https://docs.rs/axum/latest/axum/) web app. I want/need to use a Postgres connection string in URL format to connect, which seems not to be supported by deadpool-postgres. So I have to use the `Config` object of the underlying [tokio_postgres](https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.7.10/tokio_postgres/) directly.

This worked fine for my local test database, but on the target system (in this case: a DigitalOcean App and hosted Postgres) I use `sslmode=require`. So I have to setup TLS for my database connection. Here is my code so far:

```
async fn create_pool(connection_string: &str) -> anyhow::Result<Pool> {
    let pg_config = tokio_postgres::Config::from_str(connection_string)?;
    let mgr_config = ManagerConfig {
        recycling_method: RecyclingMethod::Fast
    };
    // https://docs.rs/rustls/latest/rustls/#getting-started
    let mut root_store = rustls::RootCertStore::empty();
    root_store.add_trust_anchors(
        webpki_roots::TLS_SERVER_ROOTS
            .iter()
            .map(|ta| {
                rustls::OwnedTrustAnchor::from_subject_spki_name_constraints(
                    ta.subject,
                    ta.spki,
                    ta.name_constraints,
                )
            })
    );
    // https://crates.io/crates/tokio-postgres-rustls
    let config = rustls::ClientConfig::builder()
        .with_safe_defaults()
        .with_root_certificates(root_store)
        .with_no_client_auth();
    let tls = tokio_postgres_rustls::MakeRustlsConnect::new(config);
    let mgr = Manager::from_config(pg_config, tls, mgr_config);
    Ok(Pool::builder(mgr).max_size(16).build()?)
}
```

In my logs I see:

```
Client auth requested but no cert/sigscheme available    
Error occurred while creating a new object: error performing TLS handshake: invalid peer certificate: UnknownIssuer
```

I have basic knowledge about SSL/TLS, but not too deep. I can connect to the hosted database via psql from my local machine, so no special certificate should be required.

Any hint how to get this working would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the certificate, as the handshake failed. I solved a similar issue by setting up both `localhost` and the name of my machine in my `/etc/hosts` file. Then always fill in the FQDN, use the machine name on the CA and 'localhost' for the certificates that need to be signed by the CA. Also, you need to copy the certificates to the database server and add them to `postgres.conf`